# Отцовский елемент

Tags: jquery

на странице повторяется вот такая конструкция:

```
<div class="blok">
    <p>Большая статья</p>
    <a href="#" class="link">раскрыть</a>
</div>
```

Задача такая: нужно чтобы при клике на ссылку раскрывался именно тот блок который я раскрываю а не все с классом blok

Comment: нужно какбы раскрыть отцовский элемент. Есть такая функция в Jquery?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.blok a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('p').show();
    return false;
    });
  });
```

Comment: помоему что-то не то

Comment: Исправил. Спать пора)

Comment: угу, только еще preventDefault на ссылку вызвать, а то по якорю пойдет

Comment: `return false` уже отменяет действие по умолчанию.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.blok a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).prev('p').show();
        // как вариант $(this).closest('.blok').find('p:first').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Респект ответившим, извините за бональные вопросы. Новичок.

Comment: $(this).closest('.blok').find('p:first').show();

много магии там где она не нужна =)

Comment: я же написал "как вариант"